# Proof of Affine Principal Ideal Theorem

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I'm trying to follow the proof of the principal ideal theorem, say Theorem 7.2 in Ch. I of the Red Book, in particular the reduction to irreducible hypersurface case.

Let $A$ be finitely-generated $k$-algebra and $0 \neq f$ show that $\dim((f)) = \dim(A) - 1$. We have a decomposition into prime ideals

$$ (f) = \mathfrak{p}_1 \cap \ldots \cap \mathfrak{p}_n $$

and we wish to localize to one of the components, so we choose $g \in \mathfrak{p}_1$ and $g \notin \mathfrak{p}_i$ for $i = 2 \ldots n$. In order to complete the reduction we need to show that

- $\dim(A_g) = \dim(A)$
- $\dim(\mathfrak{p}_1 A_g) = \dim(\mathfrak{p}_1)$
- $\sqrt{f/1} = \mathfrak{p}_1 A_g$

I guess the first can be argued by transcendence degrees, but not at all clear how to prove the second step?

Answer (score 1):

So I think the proof could be elaborated on the following lines

- $A$ and $A_g$ have the same field of fractions, so transcendence degree is the same
- Similarly $\dim(\mathfrak{p}) = \dim(A / \mathfrak{p}) = \dim((A / \mathfrak{p})_\bar{g}) = \dim(A_g / \mathfrak{p}_g) = \dim(\mathfrak{p} A_g)$
- The minimal primes of $f/1$ correspond to the minimal primes of $f$ not containing $g$